# Como Resolver Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: java, netbeans

Al darle Click en el botón Agregar es cuando me esta dando la Exeption
Mi botón de Aceptar es el botón que correo todo el programa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También, no estoy seguro si me esta guardando esos valores en otra Variable ya que mi Variable "Med" después la voy a pasar a una función:

```
if(medica!=null){
                for(int i = 0; i< medica.getModel().getSize();i++){
                    System.out.println(medica.getModel().getElementAt(i));
                    Med[i]=medica.getModel().getElementAt(i);
                }
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se te olvido tu escribir los Medicamentos");
            }
```

codigo de los botones Agregar, Borrar y Eliminar
(medica es una JList)

```
private void AgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    lista.addElement(this.textField.getText());
    //Enviar datos al JList
    this.medica.setModel(lista);

}                                       

private void BRRActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    lista.removeAllElements();
    this.medica.setModel(lista);
}                                   

private void eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int g=medica.getSelectedIndex();
    lista.remove(g);
}
```

Comment: Agrega la línea concreta donde se produce la excepción. Esto se debe a que en tiempo de ejecución está haciendo un *casting* sobre un objeto cuyo tipo no es asignable al declarado.